# undelphix error message

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I've installed unDelphiX to my Delphi 2010, but I can't run even a simple example program, I always an error message:

> F2051 Unit D3DX9 was compiled with a different version of Direct3D9.TD3DFormat

I never worked with unDelphiX and I have no idea what this error means.
Can someone please explain it to me and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

Just Google for "was compiled with a different version of" (exact phrase) and you will find plenty of answers. Basically, the dcu files you are using have been compiled with a different version of Delphi than the Delphi version you are using.

Link to the Delphi Documentation: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_version_conflict_xml.html

Doc doesn't clarify much though. What you need to do to resolve it:

- Compile the sources of the library with your Delphi version or obtain the dcu's compiled with the same Delphi version as yours.
- Make sure that your environment or project's library path includes the folder in which either the library sources or the dcu's compiled with your Delphi version can be found.

Comment: I did compile them with my Delphi before installation. I tried unninstalling, compiling and installing again, and nothing.

Comment: and I do have the library path included

Comment: Well, unfortunately, the compiler is never wrong in these cases. You may have conflicting environment and project library paths and/or you may have dcu's compiled with a different Delphi version in one of the "earlier" folders on one of your paths. Search your drive(s) for instances of the offending unit (d3dx9) and you should find the culprit.

Comment: Also, if you have the sources, then simply make sure the source folder is on your path and not the dcu folder (I always compile/build from library sources, never from their dcu's). That should prevent any problems with dcu's of different versions, provided of course the dcu's can't be found in an "earlier" folder...

Comment: ok, I found the file and also found out that it's corrupted, and that it was repaired in later updates... well, gotta go and update, thanks